# decimal textbox accepting only positive and negative values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have few textbox like this.

```
<input type="text" class="tblTxtRanges"  />
<input type="text" class="tblTxtRanges"  />
```

I have to make this textbox accept only decimal values. Both positive and negative numbers. User can type values, copy and paste in the textbox.

I have to replace all other characters other than numbers, one dot, and one minus symbol.
There is no restriction on decimal places.
eg: of Valid entries are 
10
10.11
-11
-11.23655 etc.

---

### **What I done so far?**

```
$(document).on("keypress keyup blur", ".tblTxtRanges", function (event) {
    //this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9\.]/g,'');
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?]/g, ''));
    if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) && (event.which != 45 || $(this).val().indexOf('-') != -1)) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

As this wont solve the problen when user copy and paste a value in textbox, i added a change event function to replace the value to a valid decimal. But this is not replacing the value. (is there any error in regex? the value is same after the replace function)

```
$(document).on("change", ".tblTxtRanges", function (event) {
    var newVal = $(this).val().replace(/[^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?]/g, '');
    $(this).val(newVal);
});
```

This code is working **but not when copy paste on textbox**. 
Also we can enter the minus symbol anywher while entering. (ie. like 002-56.36).
Need a jQuery solution as i am looking for older browser compatibility.

Any better ideas? anything i can change in the regex to replace other characters?

Comment: Hmm, I'm guessing input type="number" is out of the question?

Comment: `type="number" step="0.01"` - step to make it accept float values

Comment: I prefer a jQuery solution than html5

Comment: Maybe add newVal = newVal.parseFloat(newVal);

Comment: @Xatenev Caution, while older browsers ignore and default to "text",

Comment: "many newer browsers simply do the wrong thing" - wait what? - input type number works great on all newer browsers. If you are developing for IE8 or whatever you should add it to your question. http://caniuse.com/#search=number

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is coming from the fact that you're attempting to check every keypress.  Aside from not working well with copying and pasting values, it is a frustrating experience for a user to not be able to change a value as they please (even if it means temporarily making it an invalid decimal).  Relax your validation a bit and simply test the entered value.

Rather than validate on each keypress, simply use change event to validate the entire string.  I recommend using a regular expression to ensure that the value fits the pattern.  Be prepared to complete the field with the old value in case of validation fail.

If on validation success, you save the current value (set attribute data-oldValue for instance), then on validation fail, you can restore the previous validated value (or empty if not found).

For added effect, you can add a class indicating an error to provide immediate feedback to the user that the value entered didn't take.

Comment: ok. I am using regex to replace the string on change event and is not working. you have a better regex to make it work on change?

Comment: @Sharon You don't need to replace anything.  You only need to know if it is a string that could be a valid decimal or not.

Comment: the requirement is like i have to strip off the characters other than the decimal and the negative symbol.

Comment: Be careful to change the value *inside* the change event.  You will trigger change event again.

Answer (score 0):

The 'step' attribute worked for me.